# measure is equal to its sup

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be Lebesgue measurable. I am trying to show   (letting $m$ denote Lebesgue measure and $m_*$ denote outer measure).

$$m(E) = \sup \{m(F)\}$$

where the supremum is taken over all closed subsets $F$ of $E$.

For this can I prove $\leq$ and $\geq$ and for the first one, can I swap $m(E)$ for $m_*(E):=\inf\{\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \vert Q_j \vert \}$ Or should I appeal to the fact that there exists a closed subset of $E$ such that the measure of the set difference is small.
Just a hint will suffice.

Question, is $\sup_{F \subset E, \text{closed}} \{m(F)\}$ defined to be the closed (maximal) subset of $E$, call it $F_M$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have that

$$m(E \setminus F_M)<\epsilon$$

? Then I am pretty much done? No need for appealing to outer measure.

Comment: what is "Let" measure?

Comment: sorry meant Leb short for Lebesgue I will edit!

Comment: Am I pretty much done? does existence of this closed $F_M \subset E$ give it to me? I want to say that the this $F_M$ is the sup?

Comment: Because from definition of being Lebesgue measurable using an open set to approximate one can take complement and the complement of the open set containing the complement to construct this $F_M$?

Comment: $m$ and $m_*$ agree on all measurable sets. The only difference between them is that $m_*$ is defined for all sets, while $m$ is only defined for measurable ones. $\sup_{F \subset E, \text{closed}} \{m(F)\}$ is *defined* to be the supremum of the measures of all closed subsets of $E$. Anything else you can say about it would a *theorem* that must be proved.